# No suitable run configuration found

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

I want to create a robo script for test lab in firebase. When I click on Record Robo Script I get a prompt No suitable run configuration found in Andriod Studio.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx97k.png)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that there is at least one run configuration in your Android Studio project, for example, a run configuration to run/debug your app.

Comment: Where do you go do that?